# Why my function doesn´t redirect using window.location.href?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a function in javascript linked to a form that check cookies and log in, so when it does all the checks and everithing is ok it shows a confirm popup and if the user clicks in ok it should link to another internal page but it doesn´t, I mean, it shows the confirm popup but it doesn´t redirect.
I have tried window.location.href and window.location.replace but nothing works.

```
function checkCookies() {





    var emailValue = document.getElementById("nombre").value;

      var passValue = document.getElementById("pass1").value;


      var correct_email = checkCookie("email", emailValue);
      var correct_pass = checkCookie("pass", passValue);

      if (correct_email == -1) {
        alert("Password or email are wrong")
      } else if (correct_pass == -1) {
        alert("Password or email are wrong")

      } else if (correct_pass === correct_email) {
        alert("Log in succesfully")
        window.location.href = "principal.html";
      } else {
        alert("Password or email are wrong")
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you see

> Log in succesfully

On the screen and then nothing happens, try to replace this line:

```js
window.location.href = "principal.html";
```

with

```js
location.assign("/principal.html");
```

I assume that `/principal.html` is in the same directory we're currently in while checking cookies or in the root.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
document.location.replace("principal.html").
```

also, what error are you getting?